# Python module behaves when run alone, but not when imported as part of a wrapper

Tags: python, python-import

I am trying to write a wrapper around a package which I have created

I have the following python package structure:

```
package1
|--__init__.py (blank)
|--module1.py
|--module2.py
|--module3.py

package2
|--module4.py
```

---

#### package1.module1:

```
import module2
from module3 import *

def main():
  # Do some stuff
  module2.doSomeModule2Stuff()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

---

#### package2.module4:

```
import package1

def main():
  package1.module1.main()
```

I installed `package1` locally using `python -m pip install -e package1` so I can import it into `package2`

When I run `python module1.py` (in `package1` directory), it runs fine without issues.

When I run `python module4.py` (in `package2` directory), I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "module4.py", line 3, in <module>
  package1.module1.main()
AttributeError: module 'package1' has no attribute 'module1'
```

What do I need to change in `package1` so that I can use it in `package2` in this way?

## Edit 1

Changing `import package1` to `import package1.module1` results now in the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "module4.py", line 1, in <module>
    import package1.module1
File "/home/ben/Documents/package1/package1/module1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import module2
ImportError: No module named 'module2'
```

Comment: You need to set up your Python path to point to your module.

Comment: Try `python -m package1.module1` from outside the project directory. If it's not properly installed, you'll get a similar error.

Comment: @MadPhysicist that's not the issue - I can install the package into a `venv` and import it just fine, the problem here is I can't use the functions from it in `package2` without getting these errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Importing a package does not automatically import all its submodules, so `import package1` is not necessarily enough to access `package1.module1`. Try:

```
import package1.module1
```

You can also do:

```
from package1 import module1

def main():
    module1.main()
```

or

```
from package1.module1 import main

def my_main():  # names of mains must be different
    main()
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion, edited my original question to show result

Comment: @nagyben easiest solution for that is `from package1 import module2`. You could also consider a relative import or setting PYTHONPATH.